# LinearLayout on android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout

I was trying to create a sign up form for my Android application

This is my XML code

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mynumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Number +961"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Number"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCreateAccount"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_create" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you notice the first LinearLayout has a horizontal orientation and gravity (I want both the textview and edit text to be next to each others)

After the first linear layout i want the create account button to come out

However it is showing up on the same line with the previous edit text and text view

Any idea if i should change in the settings of the second linear layout

Comment: can u share what layout design u want to create

Comment: @PerlDeveloper im still new to stackoverflow so i cant share any pic

Comment: Are you saying you want there to be two rows, one with a text view and an `EditText` and another with the second `LinearLayout`?

Comment: @PerlDeveloper The current design is something like (Number - Edit text - create button ) all of them on the same line . I want that both the number and edit end up on the same line and the create account on line bellow them

Comment: @EranGoldin check what i wrote to PerlDeveloper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:color="@android:color/white"
            android:id="@+id/mynumber"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Number +961"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:hint="Number"
            android:id="@+id/editTextNumber"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/ic_create"
        android:id="@+id/buttonCreateAccount"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: small issue . the create button is filling the whole screen down

Comment: change `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` of Button to `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Xml File 
Use Relative layout Or One MAin LinearLayout with Vertical Orientation and in sub take Horizontal as you required.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mynumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Number +961"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:color="@android:color/white" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Number"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"  >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCreateAccount"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_create" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/sign">
    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1200dp">
     <TableLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <TextView
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:hint="Signup for Juju's"
                  android:textSize="35dp"
                  android:textColor="#f45"
                  android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TableRow
                    android:weightSum="20"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:id="@+id/nametv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="First Name"
                        android:textSize="25dp"
                        android:textColor="#23f" />

                    <EditText
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="15"
                        android:id="@+id/name"
                        android:layout_width="220dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Enter your name" >
                    </EditText>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="20"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:textColor="#23f"
                        android:id="@+id/emailtv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Email"
                        android:textSize="25dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:layout_weight="15"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:id="@+id/email"
                        android:layout_width="220dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Enter E-mail" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:weightSum="20"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:textColor="#23f"
                        android:id="@+id/phonetv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Phone"
                        android:textSize="25dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="15"
                        android:id="@+id/phone"
                        android:layout_width="220dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Enter Phone Number" />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    android:weightSum="20"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:textColor="#23f"
                        android:id="@+id/addresstv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Address"
                        android:textSize="25dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="15"
                        android:id="@+id/address"
                        android:layout_width="220dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Enter Address" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:weightSum="20"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:textColor="#23f"
                        android:id="@+id/usernametv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Username"
                        android:textSize="25dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:layout_weight="15"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:id="@+id/username"
                        android:layout_width="220dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Username" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:weightSum="20"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:textColor="#23f"
                        android:id="@+id/passwordtv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Password"
                        android:textSize="25dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="15"
                        android:id="@+id/password"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:layout_width="220dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Password" />
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:weightSum="20"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:textColor="#23f"
                        android:id="@+id/confirmtv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Reenter"
                        android:textSize="25dp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="15"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:id="@+id/confirm"
                        android:layout_width="220dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Confirm Password" />
                </TableRow>

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/view_password"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="View Password" 
                    android:textColor="#000"/>

                <ImageView
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:id="@+id/submit"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="122dp"
                        android:layout_height="74dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/button" />
                </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout type;

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely. What your are doing is encapsulating the second LinearLayout inside the first LinearLayout, that dictates a horizontal layout, ultimately resulting in horizontal positioning of all three components. Your hierarchy is as follows:

LinearLayout-Horizontal[TextView + EditText + LinearLayout-Vertical[Button]]

When supplying a LinearLayout with an orientation parameter, you're telling it to arrange all its children in that manner.

What I would recommend to you, to achieve the desired look is either:

1. Use a RelativeLayout (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) and position the elements in relation to each other and their parent.
2. Nest several LinearLayouts(not a recommended practice; here it wouldn't prove an issue but in larger and more complex layouts nesting too many such components may ultimately result in long rendering time for your view). This solution is pretty similar to what you have now and would work as follows:

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="center_vertical"
           android:orientation="horizontal" >

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/mynumber"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Number +961"
           android:textSize="20sp"
           android:color="@android:color/white" />

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/editTextNumber"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:hint="Number"
           android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
      </LinearLayout>

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/buttonCreateAccount"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
          android:background="@drawable/ic_create" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```

Here you tell your outer layout to position its children vertically, where one of its children is a LinearLayout that positions its children horizontally, resulting in:

[[TEXT][EDIT]]
[   BUTTON   ]

Hope this helps.